# what is the difference between do/tap operator and other observable operator?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Would someone be able to explain in simple language the difference between the normal observable operators we use to observe the output and do/tap seems to have the same functionality. Why do we use do/tap?

Comment: There's no such thing as `normal observable operators`, they all have their own specific use cases. [This link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) gives a very good intro to all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `do/tap` operator or `tap` operator in RxJS v6+ differs from all other operators in that it does not modify the items passed through it in any way. The results of the passed function are not considered for further processing (the return type is void).

This makes it safer to execute code that has "side-effects", i.e. code that modifies a state outside the Observable pipe. A classic example would be the use `console.log` inside a `tap` function, because the invocation of that function runs code that alters the Browser's state.

Also, if you absolutely need to alter variables or attributes before the `subscribe()` you should also do this inside the `tap` function. Otherwise, you potentially break the pure-ness of the Observable pipe (pure-ness means, you always get the same output for the same input).

Be careful about altering the item emitted to the `tap` operator, as this **WILL** change the behaviour for the other pipes **AND** alter the end result (thus again breaking the pure-ness).